# Create a Map from a CSV type data

Tags: java

I have the following data stored in a ".txt" file:

```
Dave,40,04/05/1978
Scott,34,05/06/1986
Sam,24,04/05/1978
Love,32,04/06/1989
Harry,29,04/06/1989
```

I have used the `BufferedReader` to read, split (using `,`) and store it in a `String[] stringArray`.

Now `stringArray[0]` will have name, `stringArray[1]` will have number and `stringArray[2]` will have date.

I am now looking to build a `HashMap` like below to display the key as date (in `String`) and value as `List` of `Member`s having the same date of birth

Expected output:

```
DOBMap: {04-05-1978=[[Dave,40],[Same,24]], 05/06/1986=[[Scott,34]], 04/06/1989=[[Love,32],[Harry,29]]
```

I have `Member` which has the following variables:

```
private String name;
private String no;
private String DOB;
```

Since I am a novice for collections, I am seeking help to achieve this `DOBMap` output.

Comment: Did you try to google "java hasmap tutorial"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just iterate through all of the members and insert them in a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). I used [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) in this example, but if you would like, I can rewrite it with a regular array.

So lets say you have an ArrayList called `members`.

```
// members is an ArrayList of Member objects

HashMap<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> dobMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Member m : members) {
    String[] temp = {m.getName(), m.getNo()}; // e.g. [Dave, 40]
    // already in the map, so just push it to the existing ArrayList in there
    if (dobMap.containsKey(m.getDOB())) {
        dobMap.get(m.getDOB()).add(temp); // e.g. [[Dave, 40]].add([Sam, 24])
    } else { // not in the map yet, so push a new ArrayList to that spot
        ArrayList<String[]> temp2 = new ArrayList<>();
        temp2.add(temp); // e.g. [[Dave, 40]]
        dobMap.put(m.getDOB(), temp2);
    }
}
```

A slightly different solution (using an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList` instead of an `ArrayList` of `String[]`):

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> dobMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Member m : members) {
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    temp.add(m.getName());
    temp.add(m.getNo());
    if (dobMap.containsKey(m.getDOB())) {
        dobMap.get(m.getDOB()).add(temp);
    } else {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> temp2 = new ArrayList<>();
        temp2.add(temp);
        dobMap.put(m.getDOB(), temp2);
    }
}
```

With that, you can simply run `System.out.println(dobMap);` and see that the result is exactly as you expect. Printing the `HashMap` from the first solution will require some effort to print out the contents of the `HashMap` since it won't print the regular array nicely like it does for `ArrayList`. But they both store the information in the same way.

But I think instead of storing an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`, you should just be storing it as an `ArrayList` of `Member`. So I will show a third solution, which is this:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Member>> dobMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Member m : members) {
    if (dobMap.containsKey(m.getDOB())) {
        dobMap.get(m.getDOB()).add(m);
    } else {
        ArrayList<Member> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        temp.add(m);
        dobMap.put(m.getDOB(), temp);
    }
}
```

And then override `toString()` in `Member` like so:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("[%s, %s]", this.name, this.no);
}
```

This third solution seems to be the most clear.

---

In this example, I used the following `Member` class as a basis:

```
class Member {
    private String name, no, dob;
    public Member(String name, String no, String dob) {
       this.name = name;
       this.no = no;
       this.dob = dob;
    }
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public String getNo() { return this.no; }
    public String getDOB() { return this.dob; }
}
```

An example of how you might define your `ArrayList` of `Member` object would be:

```
// parts is an array of length 3 like you said
ArrayList<Member> members = new ArrayList<>();
members.add(new Member(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks Michael... This explains the logic and any layman can understand... Thanks again for putting it is simple terms and snippets... This helped me a lot.... cheers... :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do better by using Java Stream API (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).
Here I assume that your Memeber class has the constructor:

```
Member(String[] array)
```

In which case the following:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;

public class SO1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath = ".../src/main/resources/SO1.txt";

        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))) {

            Map<String, List<Member>> map = lines
                    .map(line -> line.split(","))
                    .map(Member::new)
                    .collect(groupingBy(Member::getDOB));

            System.out.println(map);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

prints:

```
{05/06/1986=[Member{name='Scott', no='34', dob='05/06/1986'}], 04/05/1978=[Member{name='Dave', no='40', dob='04/05/1978'}, Member{name='Sam', no='24', dob='04/05/1978'}], 04/06/1989=[Member{name='Love', no='32', dob='04/06/1989'}, Member{name='Harry', no='29', dob='04/06/1989'}]}
```

Arguably, the intent of this code is more clear then a code that iterates explicitly.